# NodeJS SiriWave Electron

Tags: angularjs, node.js

So I'm trying to integrate `https://github.com/caffeinalab/siriwavejs` and an application running on Electron using nodejs.

I added the following to the main index.html file.

```
    <div ng-include="'node_modules/siriwavejs/test.html'"></div>
```

But when running npm start it doesn't render.

I'm guessing there's some sort of compatibility issue with the siriwavejs script and Electron.

Care to shed any ideas?

Comment: where is angular ...

Comment: My bad, no angular used here.